# Avoid duplicates rows which have one different column value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a view like this . I'm using SQL Server.

```
formId    name    mark
100       Rob      N
101       Rob      N
101       Rob      C
105       Jane     N
106       Jane     N
```

view name: view_example

There, some formId's have two kinds of mark values as N and C. and some have single values as N. I want to print this to a report if  formid is duplicating with different mark values, print the raw with mark  value C . If form id is not duplicating print the value as it is.
out put should look like this

```
formId    name   mark
 100      Rob     N
 101      Rob     C
 105      Jane    N
 106      Jane    N
```

I want to write the SQL query for this.

Comment: What are other possible values for `mark` column besides `C` and `N`?

Comment: Only C and N. Nothing else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `GROUP BY` all the columns where you want to preserve all the values, and apply an aggregate function (in this case - `MIN`, in order to give `C` precedence over `N`) on the `mark` column:

```
SELECT   formId, name, MIN(mark) AS mark
FROM     my_table
GROUP BY formId, name
```